# PyQT5: Drag and drop then download outlook email (.msg)

Tags: python, pyqt5

i am reviewing all the drag and drop tutorials but I am not able to find anything that allows me to drag then download the .msg file as if i just drag it from outlook to windows directory. Reading up on QDataStream, i thought i could write the mimedata to a QFile to create the .msg file but the app crashes as soon as it hits the out << event.mimeData() line.

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class TestListView(QListWidget):
    trigger = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, type, parent=None):
        super(TestListView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(72, 72))

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasFormat("FileContents"):
            event.acceptProposedAction()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasFormat("FileContents"):
            event.acceptProposedAction()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasFormat("FileContents"):
            event.acceptProposedAction()
           # print(event.mimeData().data())
            file = QFile('test.msg')
            file.open(QIODevice.WriteOnly)
            out = QDataStream(file)
            #print(event.mimeData().text())
            #trying to capture mimedata to create the actual .msg
            out << event.mimeData()
        else:
            event.ignore()

class MainForm(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainForm, self).__init__(parent)
        self.view = TestListView(self)
        #self.view.trigger.connect(self.emailDropped)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)

    def emailDropped(self, l):

        for url in l:
            print(url)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MainForm()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Below is the return of event.mimeData().formats() when i tried to drag an email in-

```
['application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="RenPrivateSourceFolder"', 'application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="RenPrivateLatestMessages"', 'application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="RenPrivateMessages"', 'application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="RenPrivateItem"', 'application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="FileGroupDescriptor"', 'application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="FileGroupDescriptorW"', 'application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="FileNameW"', 'application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="FileContents"', 'application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="Object Descriptor"', 'text/plain', 'application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="CSV"', 'application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="DragImageBits"', 'application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="DragContext"']
```

Answer (score 2):

Couldnt get it to work with just qt module but i was able to download the .msg using win32com.client. The idea is that since I will be dragging from outlook client anyways, i could use win32com to download the current highlighted selections.

```
import win32com.client as win32

def dropEvent(self, event):
    if event.mimeData().hasFormat("FileContents"):
        event.acceptProposedAction()
        outlook = win32.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
        selection = outlook.ActiveExplorer().Selection
        count = selection.Count + 1
        for i in range(1,count):
            message = selection.Item(i)
            name = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', ' ', str(message.subject))
            message.SaveAs(os.path.join(r'C:\Users\path',name + '.msg'))
            self.trigger.emit(name)
```

Comment: Cheers! This was a lifesaver

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: this answer has been edited after some clarification provided by the OP, so it's not an «actual» answer, as it doesn't provide the final expected result.

---

QDataStream `<<` operand doesn't accept python strings or QObjects:

```
>>> stream << self.something.text()
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for <<: 'QDataStream' and 'str'
```

The operand is only available for known compatible and serializable Qt types (see documentation for PyQt [`QDataStream.__lshift__()`](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/api/qtcore/qdatastream.html)), such as QByteArray, QdateTime, etc. Otherwise you'll better go with `QDataStream.write*` methods:

```
>> stream.writeQString(self.something.text())
```

### Update, after question editing and comments

The `msg` format that Outlook uses is not considered a "common" standard, and I can't provide you with a definite and complete answer for your issue. You'll need to dig into the [`MS-OXMSG` Outlook Item file format](https://interoperability.blob.core.windows.net/files/MS-OXMSG/%5bMS-OXMSG%5d.pdf) to understand how to write your own files.

That said, each and any field of a mime data object is accessible through `mimeData.data([format])`, which returns a QByteArray that is ready to be written to a QDataStream used with an *opened* QFile. That's also the reason `out << event.mimeData()` doesn't work: it's a QObject, which is not directly serializable.

Given the formats you gave before, for example, you can access the "FileNameW" item using the following:

```
mimeData.data('application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="FileNameW"')
```

Now it's up to you to "build" your own msg file, following the documentation given above. I know this is not an *actual* answer, but I don't use Outlook and cannot provide you even the simplest example possible, since I'm not able to test it accordingly.

A final suggestion: remember to call `file.close()` at the end, otherwise the file won't be written at all.

Comment: I am trying to download the entirety of the mimeData, so that it saves as the actual .msg file that i can double click and open in outlook. However writeQstring doesnt accomplish that as it doesnt take in event.mimeData()

Comment: You didn't ask about that. If you want to get the whole contents of the mimeData you have to specify it, as in your question you just complained about the crash and in the example you only wrote about the text content. If you need that, edit your question and be more specific. You can't expect us to help you with X if you ask about Y. What do you want to save to the file? The whole mime data? The original contents? Also I think it would helpful if you'd also provide an example of all mimeData contents you want to get.

Comment: Anyway, be aware that it's possible that you will *never* get the contents you'd expect: the d'n'd contents completely depend on what the original program provides, which means that, if the program doesn't provide a "respectful" representation of the email contents, there's no way Qt will get the whole original message contents.

Comment: I guess my print(event.mimeData().text()) statement caused some confusion? I thought from the the title and me point out the out << event.mimeData() would provide enough clarification. I've edited the post to include more details, thank you.

Comment: @Ken I've updated my answer. Unfortunately I don't have Outlook and cannot help you further with your issue, since the `msg` is not a standard and I cannot test it using other programs. If you find a solution, I'd suggest to answer your own question afterwards.

Comment: Appreciate it. I've added my approach.